# Jquery datatable creating extra header on chrome browser when using scrollX property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

```
('#instant-quotes').DataTable({
    "data": dataSet,
    "scrollY": yscroll,
    /*"initComplete": function(settings, json) {
    $('#instant-quotes thead tr:first').remove();
    },*/
    "dom": "lfrti",
    "scrollCollapse": false,
    "bSortCellsTop": false,
    "info": false,
    "processing": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "searching": false,
    "pageLength": 7,
    "order": [ 0, "desc" ]...
})
```

When i use the datatable with the scrollX property it always append a blank `<thead>` with a `<tr>`.I dont why this occurs but its always doing this,however i removed by using jquery

```
$('#instant-quotes thead tr:first').remove()
```

But i dont think so its a good solution because when i sort or redraw the table then this blank `<thead>` again appears, also when i change the layout (coz its responsive) then it appears again,
Kindly suggest a better and optimal solution.

Comment: Why do you want to remove in a first place?

Comment: rather than removing try hiding i.e. $('#instant-quotes thead tr:first').hide()

Comment: its adding the blank `<thead>` which creating the head section more big and ugly

Comment: @ParagBhayani i tried hide functionality but its not working though.

Comment: try hiding whole thead $('#instant-quotes thead').hide()

Comment: @ParagBhayani if i did this then the original `<head>` will stop showing which is not the good solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115826/discussion-between-parag-bhayani-and-sudhanshu-saxena).

Comment: try it by adding CSS #instant-quotes thead tr:first { 
display:none !important; 
}

Comment: A small thought. Could you please do 2 small tests 1) Remove the "dom" property from the data table initialization and check the result 2) Just change the "scrollCollapse" to "true" and check the result.

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

Comment: i removed that, But on sorting it appears again.Also i used the `scrollCollapse` but nothing change